# Transformed distribution involving logistic equation solution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

Suppose I solve the logistic equation (with $y(0) = 1$ at $t=10$),

$$y(10) = \frac{\kappa  e^{10 r}}{\kappa +e^{10 r}-1},$$

where $\kappa$ is the carrying capacity and $r$ is the initial growth rate.

Further suppose that I have the following uncertainty about the inputs: $r\sim U(0,1)$ and $\kappa \sim U(10,20)$. I can simulate what the distribution of $y(10)$ looks like,

```
fSampleRK[] := {RandomReal[{0, 1}], RandomReal[{10, 20}]}
fLogistic[r_, \[Kappa]_, t_, a_] := (a E^(r t) \[Kappa])/(-a + a E^(r t) + \[Kappa])
fSampleQ[t_, a_] := Block[{lRK = fSampleRK[]}, fLogistic[lRK[[1]], lRK[[2]], t, a]]
Histogram[Table[fSampleQ[10, 1], {100000}], 100]
```

Yielding the monstrosity below,

[image]

I rather optimistically tried the following,

```
aDist = TransformedDistribution[(E^(10 r) \[Kappa])/(-1 + E^(10 r) + \[Kappa]), 
        {r \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}], 
        \[Kappa] \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 10}]}]
PDF[aDist, Q]
```

But Mathematica falls over and returns the bottom line unevaluated.

Can anyone think of a way to determine the analytic PDF here?

(Of course I can sample and fit a kernel density estimator to the samples, but I am looking for an analytic result.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "11.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 11, 2017)" *)

aDist = TransformedDistribution[
   (E^(10 r) κ)/(-1 + E^(10 r) + κ),
   {r \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 1}],
    κ \[Distributed] UniformDistribution[{0, 10}]}];
```

Although Mathematica cannot determine a closed-form representation for `aDist`, it can still do **some** calculations with it.

```
mean = Mean[aDist] // FullSimplify

(* (1/200)*(-10 + 2*E^10*(5 - (-2 + E^10)*ArcTanh[5/(4 + E^10)]) - 100*Log[10] + 
      Log[-1 + E^10] + 99*Log[9 + E^10]) *)

mean // N

(* 4.09884 *)

stdDev = StandardDeviation[aDist] // Simplify

(* 1/(200*Sqrt[-(3/(-35700 + 406000*Log[5] + 
                60000*Log[5]*Log[10] - 30000*Log[10]^2 - 
                460*Log[-1 + E^10] - 600*Log[5]*Log[-1 + E^10] + 
                3*Log[-1 + E^10]^2 + 200*Log[2]*
                  (2030 + 300*Log[10] - 3*Log[-1 + E^10] - 
                     297*Log[9 + E^10]) + 3*E^40*
                  (Log[-1 + E^10] - Log[9 + E^10])^2 - 
                405540*Log[9 + E^10] - 59400*Log[5]*
                  Log[9 + E^10] + 594*Log[-1 + E^10]*
                  Log[9 + E^10] + 29403*Log[9 + E^10]^2 + 
                2*E^20*(-3850 + 9*Log[-1 + E^10]^2 - 
                     6*Log[-1 + E^10]*(-85 + 50*Log[2] + 
                          50*Log[5] - 47*Log[9 + E^10]) + 
                     30*(-17 + 10*Log[5] + Log[1024])*
                       Log[9 + E^10] - 291*Log[9 + E^10]^2) + 
                4*E^10*(10850 + 45*Log[-1 + E^10] - 
                     3*Log[-1 + E^10]^2 + 300*Log[2]*
                       (-5 + Log[-1 + E^10] - Log[9 + E^10]) + 
                     300*Log[5]*(-5 + Log[-1 + E^10] - 
                          Log[9 + E^10]) + 1455*Log[9 + E^10] - 
                     294*Log[-1 + E^10]*Log[9 + E^10] + 
                     297*Log[9 + E^10]^2) - 
                4*E^30*(3*Log[-1 + E^10]^2 + Log[-1 + E^10]*
                       (185 - 6*Log[9 + E^10]) + Log[9 + E^10]*
                       (-185 + 3*Log[9 + E^10]))))]) *)

stdDev // N

(* 2.67158 *)
```

While working with the `PDF` is a problem, the `CDF` can be numerically evaluated

```
CDF[aDist, 10]

(* 1 *)

median = x /. FindRoot[CDF[aDist, x] == 1/2, {x, 3}]

(* 3.63448 *)

Plot[CDF[aDist, x], {x, 0, 10},
 Epilog -> {Red, Dashed, Line[{{median, 0}, {median, 1/2}, {0, 1/2}}]}]
```

[image]

```
data = RandomVariate[aDist, 10000];

bDist = FindDistribution[data, RandomSeeding -> 1]

(* MixtureDistribution[{0.317651, 0.406901, 
  0.275448}, {NormalDistribution[1.73085, 0.85307], 
  UniformDistribution[{0.00174172, 9.99195}], 
  UniformDistribution[{0.00174172, 9.99195}]}] *)

Show[
 Histogram[data, Automatic, "PDF"],
 Plot[PDF[bDist, x], {x, 0, 10}]]
```

[image]

```
Show[Histogram[data, Automatic, "CDF"],
 Plot[{CDF[aDist, x], CDF[bDist, x]}, {x, 0, 10},
  PlotStyle -> {Red, Blue},
  BaseStyle -> Thick,
  PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.25, .75}]]]
```

[image]